# Clean Win 7 Install - Missing Drivers :(

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I have a PC that I just did a clean install of Windows 7 on, it's all installed and I'm on the desktop.

But I'm having trouble connecting to the internet.

I have nothing under "local network connections" and I'm missing these drivers :(

[image]

What can I do? / where are the drivers?
Will this fix my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Most computers come with either a restore image (that includes all drivers, software, etc. that shipped with the PC), or they come with a bare Windows install disk, and a drivers/software installer disk.... Do you not have the original disks for this PC? If not, you will need a second PC to download stuff to and copy to a USB drive, or if that won't get recognized due to drivers, burned to a CD/DVD and then installed on the target computer.

Comment: I had to buy an external DVD drive to use my Win 7 disc. The PC is an old PC I was given and I don't have original discs which is why I wiped the PC and did a clean install with my license. I'm in the process of downloading all the drivers I can find, but if they don't work I don't know what to do. It's a Foxconn NT i2847.

Comment: Drivers for this seem easy to find, http://www.foxconnchannel.com/ProductDetail.aspx?T=NanoPC&U=en-us0000020, focus on the chipset and LAN drivers, if you can get those installed you can do the rest from the box, but seriously this is an old, underpowered box and will likely give sub-par performance, if Windows is not a requirement perhaps something other than Windows would be appropriate, Linux Mint 18 Mate or similar lightweight DE distro may be more suited to this hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded pretty much all of them, and now I have the network working and successfully connected to the internet. In fact the only ones I couldn't update were "PCI Simple Communications Controller" and "SM Bus Controller". The rest were updated using the drivers. I guess that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Run the tool [PCI-Z](https://www.pci-z.com/) to see which devices you have in the PC.

> PCI-Z is designed for detecting unknown hardware on your Windows based
>   PC. It will help you determine vendor, device and certain details
>   about device even if you don't have drivers installed. Software uses
>   The PCI ID Repository, a public repository of all known ID's used in
>   PCI devices: ID's of vendors, devices, subsystems and device classes.
>   It is used in various programs (e.g. The PCI Utilities) to display
>   full human-readable names instead of cryptic numeric codes. It is
>   almost similar to lspci Linux command but with full Windows support.

Now go to the vendor homepages (relatek, broadcom, nvidia) on a second PC to get the drivers. Transfer them via USb flash drive to the PC and install the missing drivers.

Comment: Ah cool. Thank you for posting. I wasn't aware of this tool. I have found the Network/Ethernet Controller drivers though and now they are working. That just leaves the "PCI Simple Communications Controller" and the "SM Bus Controller".

Comment: PCI Simple Communications could be a modem or bluetooth

Comment: All you really need to do is go into Device Manager and then the problem device properties and look for the hardware and device ID and do some simple Googling. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2089404/how-to-easily-find-drivers-for-unknown-devices-in-windows.html